# How to print Text and value from integer on the same line in the console?

Tags: c#

This is what I do, but it didn't work:

```
int money;
Console.Writeline("Enter how much money you want";
money=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Writeline("The Money you have now are",money)
```

Comment: Just concat via the strings via "+" you do not have to call ToString() on your integer value because Console.WriteLine() will automatically use the Int32.ToString method to get the text representation value of an integer.

Comment: *What* isn't working? Errors when parsing? the writeline doesn't show `Money`? It doesn't compile because your missing a `)` and `;`? [ask]

Comment: Beware of case sensitivity, Money or money ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Concatenate the strings:

   ```
   Console.Writeline("The Money you have now are" + money);
   ```
2. Use the format specifier version of [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
   Console.Writeline("The Money you have now are: {0}", money);
   ```
3. Use [`Console.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0swwx2k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

   ```
   Console.Write("The Money you have now are: ");
   Console.Writeline(money);
   ```

#### Note:

Your code doesn't actually compile due to some missing parentheses, semi-colons and incorrect casing. I would write your code as this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter how much money you want");
int money = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("The Money you have now is {0}", money);
```

Answer (score 3):

As of C# 6, this can be written as:

```
Console.Writeline($"The Money you have now are: {money}");
```

See: [$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: can you give me a link from where i can follow the new changes on C# ?

Comment: @VelikoKosev, see eg http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2015/03/26/c.net-little-wonders-string-interpolation-in-c-6.aspx. The syntax has been in a state of flux over the last few months, so many blogs etc (including MS themselves) have the wrong syntax at times, but this site seems correct. Your best bet is to download VS2015 RC and try it. (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx)